# Can I Have Two Regions Under One Amazon S3 Account?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have two wordpress blogs and I am planning to use amazon S3 with one blog and (amazon S3+cloudfront) for another blog.

I read that we need to choose a location when we start our AWS account.

However, for one site (One using cloudfront and amazon S3), my target market is US and UK and another site (Using amazon S3 alone), my target market is India.

In this case, should I use two separate accounts? Or can I have one single account with two locations? (US and Asia).

The one I am using cloudfront for will have video streaming and the one which I use S3 alone will be heavy on images.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple locations within the same account. When creating a bucket you will be given a choice in which region to create it. E.g. you can have different buckets within the same account located in the different regions.

Thanks,
Andy